# Matlab Semilogy hold on won't work

Tags: matlab, logging, plot

Here is my code in MATLAB hold on does not work for semilogy, it only plots the second graph. Any help appreciated.

```
`figure

semilogy(T_mean,p_th, '-ob'); hold on;
semilogy(T_mean,p_me, '-or'); hold off;
axis([250,500, 1E16, 1E19])
grid on
title('Theoretical and Measured Carrier Concentrations)')
xlabel('Tempeature (K)')
ylabel('Carrier Concentration (cm^-3)')`
```

Comment: That should work. Are you sure the range of the data from the 1st plot is correct?

Comment: yes ranges are correct. It only plots the last one.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that we could plot and try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I'd check that `p_th` and `p_me` are different (I've made that mistake before).

Comment: p_th=[9.27725345074262e+17
9.27725345074201e+17
9.27725345073642e+17], p_me=[4.53274800000000e+17
4.55687900000000e+17
4.57123300000000e+17], T_mean=[299.850100000000
324.542150000000
349.372450000000]   Here is a simplified data it contains more, all data are in the axis limit range.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me (Ubuntu, R2014b):

```
p_th=[9.27725345074262e+17 9.27725345074201e+17 9.27725345073642e+17];
p_me=[4.53274800000000e+17 4.55687900000000e+17 4.57123300000000e+17];
T_mean=[299.850100000000 324.542150000000 349.372450000000];

figure
hold on

semilogy(T_mean,p_th, '-ob');
semilogy(T_mean,p_me, '-or');
axis([250,500, 1E16, 1E19]);
grid on
title('Theoretical and Measured Carrier Concentrations)')
xlabel('Tempeature (K)')
ylabel('Carrier Concentration (cm^-3)')
```

[image: Result]